# Express query for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, express

### I am dynamically trying to pass the name of the table to SQL query in the part of express code below

**Background Information::**

- What i am passing as a (key,value) is the string which will be the
  name of a table in sql database
- why am i doing is to dynamically select the table based on a dynamic
  client request

**Problem I am facing::**

- Clearly i am not sunig the sql query correctly
- How to solve this

**[ExpressCode]**

```
app.get('/RestaurantDesc/:Key',function(request,response,next){

    var keyName=request.params.Key;
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;
    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM keyName', function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_restaurants = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );
} );
```

Comment: I'm assuming the variable keyname is intended to contain the text name of the table.  If this is right then keyname needs to be outside the string and concatenated onto the string I would think.

Comment: Yes, Your assumption is 100% correct to what i am trying to tell .... please can you put your solution in code by editing my code i posted ..... It would help a newbie like me ... thanks !

Comment: What mysql driver are you using? [This one](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)?

Answer (score 0):

Considering `keyname` and `RestaurantTimings` as the table name. Try this:-

```
app.get('/RestaurantDesc/:Key',function(request,response,next){

    var keyName=request.params.Key;
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM ', keyName, function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_restaurants = rows;
                        callback();
                });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM ', RestaurantTimings, function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    RestaurantTimings = rows;
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants,
        'RestaurantTimings' : RestaurantTimings
    });
} );
} );
```