# solving a Simple SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

### Here is a tricky problem i am trying to solve, Having difficulty in solving it

---

***Suppose there is a simple query::***

```
String College="Harvard"

SELECT * FROM College
```

- **Above Harvard is the name of the table**
- **College just has the value in it and is not the name of a table**

*Query will fail because system is assuming College as the name of the table and searching for it which is not there*

How to solve this .... in terms of SQL statements

**Hope i am clear**

*Thanks,*

Comment: @College:= "MyTable"; SELECT * FROM @College;

Comment: @ bksi .... Please can you post as the answers .... i didnt understan the query u posted ... sorry im a newbie

Comment: @Iplay:- I guess my answer is the one which you are looking for and which bksi also means!!! :) Hope this resolves your tricky query ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying like this :)

```
SET @College:='Harvard';
SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT * FROM ', @College)

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Should it not be `SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT * FROM ', @College);`

Comment: thanks .....that helps .... I posted this question to solve another problem i posted on site .... have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/q/18495186/2582071] ....  how can i apply there ... please give a feed back

Comment: You are welcome...I will try that question also!!! P.S. Dont forget to accept this as an answer if this helped you!!! :)

Comment: Please look into it .... even if you have not worked on express framework .... post your views on Mysql part of it , thanks

Comment: @Iplay:- And if that helps you too please dont forget to accept that as an answer too!!! :)